# removing a row in success funciton of ajax call

Tags: jquery

I want to remove a table's row with jquery. When i write this jQuery(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(); statement outside ajax success function it fades out row. but it does not work if written within ajax success function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.assignme').click(function(){
            id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:'home.php?ajax=1&action=assing_to_agent&application_id='+id,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data==-1)
                        alert('Assigned to someone else');
                    jQuery(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();   
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Here is html

```
 <tr>
    <td><button class="assignme" rel="<?php echo $row_rs_report['application_id']; ?>">Assign Me</button></td></tr>
```

Also if someone can tell me about a good practice to send a value to ajax method as i m sending id using rel attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your success is called the *this* statement is the window (as far as i remember). At least, it is probably not the element you were trying to refer to.

[EDIT] Actually, you could event use the *id* attribute instead of *rel*, thus, you could point to that button (as far as the id is unique) and delete its td parent.

HTML could become:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <button class="assignme" id="<?php echo $row_rs_report['application_id']; ?>">
      Assign Me
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.assignme').click(function(){
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:'home.php?ajax=1&action=assing_to_agent&application_id='+id,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data==-1)
                        alert('Assigned to someone else');
                    jQuery("#"+id).parent("td").fadeOut();   
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Declaring a var to pass arguments to the ajax is the way i use to do, maybe there is a better one.

Btw, the *var* statement can guarantee the local use of the var (safer and quicker)

Max

Comment: let me tell you u wht u remember is absolutely right. 'this' was referring to something else. i stored 'this' in a variable and then used that variable instead of 'this' in success function.

Comment: storing *this* in a var is also another way to handle the problem